# How to take the negative sign in a string

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

What pattern should i give to the following expression

```
("146d0" A + "-594d0" B)
```

so i would get

```
("146d0" A - "594d0" B)
```

Comment: Before we get into [XY problem solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's the point of this question and answer? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
("146d0" A + "-594d0" B) /. s_String?(StringStartsQ["-"]) :> -StringDrop[s, 1]

(*    "146d0" A - "594d0" B    *)
```

Answer (score -1):

This pattern seems to be working

```
("146d0" A + "-594d0" B) //. 
 Times[A_String, 
   B_] :> -StringDelete[ToString[-ToExpression[A]], " "] B /; 
   Negative[First@ToExpression[A]]
```